# Value of text field not "updating" until it loses focus in FF/IE. Works in Chrome

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I'm working on a web app and I'm using jQuery UI to move around answers in a question. If I don't click out of one of the input text boxes before I move it in FF/IE, the value is not stored. If I do click out of the text box and then move it, the value seems to be stored.

Before:

[image: before]

After:

[image: after]

I'm wondering what I need to do to "set" the value of the text box, perhaps on each keyup?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Provide some code, preferably in a [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Or http://jsbin.com. But not **just** there, in the question. (The fiddle/bin is a nice *addition*).